# change Apache setting , so for `https` it should listen 8443 instead of 443

Tags: apache, iis, ssl, solr

I am using solr in my app so i have installed bitnami on my server.

everything is running OK for me as far i not have installed ssl certificate on server . as soon i have installed ssl the problem i am getting that

http://subdomain.mysite.org/ runs OK and show me the website

but in case when i run the

https://subdomain.mysite.org/ its shows me `bitnami` page instead of website .

I understand that this is showing because of `apache` is using 443 for https but i am not able to  find where i can change that setting so instead of `443` `apache` use `8443` for `https` .

Note : My server is window server.

another possible title of my question can be :

How can i change Apache setting so for `https` it should listen 8443 instead of 443.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot achieve `https` over a different port. Reason - 443 is the standard `https` port, just as 80 is for `http`. All web clients including browsers adhere to this standard for the choice of protocol for the traffic.

If you hit your application at https://subdomain.sitename.org:8443/ it will route to your application (Solr?)

However, if you need to run it on 8443 specifically and have it work the way you wish, then you could use a reverse-proxy such as nginx, which would listen to incoming traffic at port 443 and route it to 8443 internally.

Comment: but i want that instead of using https setting of apache it should use the iis setting .

Comment: I understand. Problem is only one process would be able to listen on 443, and thus use https on a machine. If you need both Apache and IIS to use https, using a reverse proxy to listen on 443 and routing relevant traffic to IIS v/s Apache is the option I recommend

Comment: The moment you change Apache to listen on 8443, it won't be using https without specifying the port number.

Comment: I am ok with that.in case it not listen https request i am also OK with that

Comment: The moment you change Apache to listen on 8443, it won't be using https without specifying the port number. Is it possible to achieve this without reverse proxy ?

Comment: Ok - so https port is something I suppose you could change in `httpd.conf`? Ref [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/ssl/ssl_howto.html)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41575/discussion-between-rahularyansharma-and-srikanth-venugopalan)